# How to create folder in OneDriveClient

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive, windows-10-universal

How to create in `IOneDriveClient` (`OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes)`)? Not REST!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can create a folder:

```
 var folderToCreate = new Item { Name = folderName, Folder = new Folder() };
    var newFolder = await client.Drive.Items[parentId].Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/24

Comment: Another sample that creates the folder in the app's special folder: `await client.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);`